# How to wait X minutes between tests in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I am testing a website that has a page that will update 4-5 minutes after I have done a certain action.

Here's what I've thought of:

1. Thread.sleep()/Continuously refreshing page waiting for update.  This means my tests automatically get an additional 5 minutes added on.
2. I have a set of tests that are ordered by `DependsOnMethod` in a lengthy list.  I could depend the first test on the test that performs the action, and have the second test depend on the last test to run.  This option is not as bad...but it means putting the methods in a class that is completely irrelevant (and dependencies that don't make logical sense)

Are there any other options?

Note: I am using TestNG with WebDriver

Comment: Are you using testNG with Selenium/WebDriver?

Comment: Can't you just change that behaviour to a few msec for testing? Sounds quite annoying.

Comment: No.  The backend server is actually doing work for those minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution would be to use implicit or explicit waits but it depends how the page update looks like. But if it's for instance some element with counter, you should try something like.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5 * 60)) //time in seconds
    .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.id("id"), 
    "Text after update"));
```

Comment: Thats basically the answer above. If you want to be ABSOLUTELY sure that the page has loaded (that is, the elements you want to check/set have loaded), you should wait until(...list of the above elements are visible...). Otherwise, it may be possible that the element you're waiting on loads, but the one's you want to operate on do not by the time you execute some code on them, causing your test to fail.

Comment: This is option 1.  The page doesn't auto-update, so I would have to continuously refresh, and check for the element.  I know how to do that, but means a simple test takes 5 minutes.  This is NOT a webdriver question, but a TestNG question.

Comment: In that case I guess that `Thread.sleep()` is the best option